# starting to study Reporting Services

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

i am just starting to study Reporting services but on my First lesson i have two questions

1- i cant find the **Business Intelligence** > **Reporting Services** in my **Visual Studio 2013** > **New Project** > **Installed** > **Templates**

as shown here 
[image]

while i installed the reporting service on my **SQL Server 2012**

as shown here
[image]

2- can i create reports directly on my web application by right click on a folder and add report without creating another new report server project

3- can i use my entity framework as a data source for my report , if yes how to achieve this using **Visual Studio 2013** and **SQL Server 2012**

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013. This design studio is no longer called Business Intelligence Design Studio (BIDS), past VS 2013.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313